# Crear un .txt u otro formato desde un listView, Boton guardar y cargar

Tags: qt, listview

Tengo un pequeño programa donde añado elimino y busco elementos en un listView, pero ahora querria añadir un par de botones para guardar y cargar el listView en un formato texto o cualquier otro, y asi poder usarlo en sesiones posteriores aunque me encuentro con diversos problemas buscando posibles soluciones en la web, soy algo novato aun, este es mi codigo:

--

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QStringListModel>
#include <QtWidgets>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->listView->setModel(new QStringListModel(stringList));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_addButton_released()
{
    if (ui->lineEdit->text().isEmpty()|| stringList.contains(ui->lineEdit->text())) {
        QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Empty Field"),
            tr("Por favor, introduce un nuevo codigo o el codigo ya existe."));
        return;
    }else{
    stringList.append(ui->lineEdit->text());
           ((QStringListModel*) ui->listView->model())->setStringList(stringList);
           ui->lineEdit->clear();
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_removeButton_released()
{
    if (ui->lineEdit->text().isEmpty() || !stringList.contains(ui->lineEdit->text())) {
        QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Empty Field"),
            tr("El codigo ha sido ya borrado o no existe."));
        return;
    }else{
    stringList.removeOne(ui->lineEdit->text());
    ((QStringListModel*) ui->listView->model())->setStringList(stringList);
    ui->lineEdit->clear();
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_findButton_released()
{
    if (ui->lineEdit->text().isEmpty()|| !stringList.contains(ui->lineEdit->text())) {
        QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Empty Field"),
            tr("CODIGO NO ENCONTRADO"));
        return;
    }else{
        QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Empty Field"),
            tr("CODIDO ENCONTRADO!"));
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_saveButton_released()
{
}

void MainWindow::on_loadButton_released()
{
}
```

Alguien tiene idea de por donde ir

Comment: This is SO Spain, so the questions can be only in spanish. Pleas, translate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si suponemos que cada elemento de la lista se va a encontrar en una línea diferente dentro del fichero la lectura es más o menos trivial. Si nos fijamos en la [documentación](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlistmodel.html) de `QStringListModel`, vemos que podemos obtener/establecer la lista de elementos mediante un `QStringList`. La idea es volcar el contenido del fichero a un `QStringList` y después pasarle ese objeto al modelo:

```
QStringList LeerDelFichero(
  QString nombreFichero)
{
  QStringList toReturn;

  QFile textFile(nombreFichero);
  if(!textFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
    QMessageBox::information(0,"Error",textFile.errorString());
  }
  else
  {
    QTextStream textStream(&textFile);
    while (true)
    {
      QString line = textStream.readLine();
      if (line.isNull())
         break; 
      else
         toReturn.append(line);
    }
  }

  return toReturn;
}

void MainWindow::on_loadButton_released()
{
  QStringListModel* model = static_cast<QStringListModel*>(ui->listView->model());
  model->setStringList(LeerDelFichero("ruta_del_fichero"));
}
```

Y la escritura más de lo mismo... recuperamos la lista de elementos en formato `QStringList` y volcamos el contenido de dicha lista en el fichero:

```
void EscribirEnFichero(
  QString nombreFichero,
  QStringList const& listaElementos)
{
  QFile textFile(nombreFichero);
  if(!textFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
    QMessageBox::information(0,"Error",textFile.errorString());
  }
  else
  {
    QTextStream textStream(&textFile);
    for( QString const& item : listaElementos)
    {
      textStream << item << '\n';
    }
  }
}

void MainWindow::on_saveButton_released()
{
  QStringListModel* model = static_cast<QStringListModel*>(ui->listView->model());
  EscribirEnFichero("ruta_del_fichero",model->stringList());
}
```